# Image link in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, hyperlink

How can I get the image link in WordPress media?

[image]

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It shows that you need to put a custom link here if you want to connect to any site with this image. For example, you displayed this image in your site's content area where you want to click on that image and it will redirect to that specific page. Also you can put a custom link to another site whare you can set the link target, it will open in same window or in a new window. Hope it will make a sense for you.